# How can I tell Jersey to use my MessageBodyReader instead using JAXB?

Tags: jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

Basically, I have some models which all use JAXB. However, I have some highly custom functionality to convert to JSON and back so I want to write my own MessageBodyReader/Writer to do the job for me.

Right now, the writing portion is done: if i return one of my models from a REST resource, it goes through my writer. But when I try and accept a model as a FormParam, it doesnt use my MessageBodyReader and instead attempts to unmarshal it using JAXB (which fails).

So how I can tell Jersey to use my Reader instead?

```
public TestModel testProvider(@FormParam("model") TestModel input){ //doesnt work
  return new TestModel(); //this part works!
}
```

Comment: MessageBodyReaders are for consuming the entire message body.  They aren't used to consume individual form values.  If the entire message was your model instead, then use "TestModel input" without the @FormParam.

Answer (score 1):

1. Mark as @Provider
2. Add the configuration to your web.xml EX:

`<init-param><param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name> <param-value> your.package.that.contains.the.provider </param-value> </init-param>`

Answer (score 0):

Since your writer works, but your reader does not, I'm guessing you have just missed something in your configuration.  Some things to check:

- Do you have the @Provider annotation on your reader?
- Did you correctly implement the isReadable method on your reader?
- Do you have the appropriate @Consumes annotation on the reader, does its media type match the media type specified on your service method?